# Salvar cookies de uma requisição e usar em outra em seguida cURL

Tags: php, libcurl

Estou tentando fazer login em um site e salvar os cookies para ter acesso à outras páginas, encontrei a opção `'CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR'` que salva os cookies num arquivo NETSCAPE, a dúvida é como seria feita uma segunda requisição para outra URL usando outros parametros POST, usando o mesmo `$ch`, qual a melhor forma de proceder?

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://site.com.br');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'login=usuario&senha=123456');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$content = curl_exec($ch);


curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use o [`CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE.html) "apontado" para o mesmo arquivo.

```
//...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookies.txt');
//...
```

O `cookies.txt` terá os cookies escritos pelo `JAR` e será lido pelo `FILE`.

Comment: Depois eu repito os mesmos argumentos usados na requisição anterior? isso irá sobrescrever?

Comment: O `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE`apenas lê, ele pode usar o arquivo infinitamente. Já o `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` apenas escreve. Se utilizar o `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` para um mesmo arquivo ele irá sobrescrever, se tem a intenção de "fazer o login com varias contas diferentes" então cada um deverá usar um arquivo para cada um.

Comment: Essa parte eu entendi legal, digo para como prosseguir após salvar o cookie e usar o `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE`, eu devo usar os mesmos argumentos para uma nova requisição antes do curl_close, certo?

Comment: Isso depende da requisição que quer fazer, se ele for idêntica ao anterior ou não. Os outros parâmetros devem ser incluído, a inclusão do JAR, por exemplo, é opcional.